# Coding in UTF-8 problem

Tags: php, utf-8

I am using notepad++ for php coding.

I don't have any problem with format set up using Encode in ANSI.

However when I use Encode in UTF-8, either I have a strange character at the top or not showing anything.

Q1. Am I supposed to use ANSI?
Q2. Why do I am not able to display anything when I use UTF-8

My sourse code for the header is following.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello, PHPlot!</title>
</head>
```

Is that because I am not using UTF-8 in the header?

Comment: Notepad++ and their wrong labeling: The name of the encoding is ASCII and not ANSI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark). You can use the 'Encode in UTF-8 without BOM' mode in notepad++.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) has some helpful information about using UTF-8 with PHP. You will also (as you suggested) need to set the content type in either the header or a meta tag in order for the browser to interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using UTF-8 with a BOM (which has [issues](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom)) and your server is failing to [specify the encoding](https://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/#Slide0270) correctly.

IIRC, BOM is unavoidable in Notepad, so I would suggest using a better editor. I'm fond of [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) myself.

(Also note, that a [Doctype](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) is required in HTML documents)

Comment: What is your setup in Komodo Edit for Default Editor Encoding?

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Haigh says, it's probably the BOM. It's not necessary for UTF-8 encoding, so you can safely leave them out.

However I should point out that PHP has very weak support for UTF-8 - be prepared for a bumpy ride. Take a look at [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180709043534/http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8) for some details on  problems you might encounter.